# What does said mean in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

A newspaper of the ruling Communist Party ( said Saturday ) that no religion is above the law in China, urging officials to stay firm while dealing with a rare protest over the planned demolition of a massive mosque in the northwest.
is it said on Saturday ?

Comment: It's a slightly "loose" usage of ***to say***, since we usually assume people say things using their *mouth* - which a newspaper doesn't have. But idiomatically it's perfectly natural, as shown by countless instances of things like [*(I believe everything) **the Bible says***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+bible+says%22). Or even [***My watch says** it's quarter past 8*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+watch+says%22) (which *might* refer to a "talking watch", but usually wouldn't even today).

Comment: ... I'd like to say you should think of ***to say*** as meaning ***to express [something] using words*** - but even that wouldn't cover more "extreme" usages such as my "non-talking watch" example. You're right that the optional preposition ***on*** could have been included in your exact cited context. But it's not *necessary*.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to something related to a named day, British English tends to use the preposition 'on' - I'll see you on Tuesday; he paid me on Friday. American English tends to omit the preposition - they said Saturday; I'll gladly repay you Tuesday.